# Problem with qlmanage -p not working for most (but not all) files

Tags: terminal, quicklook

I'm trying to invoke quicklook from the command line via

```
qlmanage -p filename
```

Images like jpegs and pngs and pdf files work fine

```
qlmanage -p test.jpg
qlmanage -p test.png
```

However invoking the same command on any html file

```
qlmanage -p test.html
```

results in the program briefly hanging followed by:

> Segmentation fault: 11

under bash and

> 'qlmanage -p test.txt' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)

under the fish shell.

The level 4 log output runs through registering most of the QL Generators but then just halts unexpectedly and produces no more output.

It works fine invoking through the finder.

I have tried deleting all of my 3rd party QL plugins and resetting. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: I am getting the same error, `qlmanage -p hello.pdf` works but `qlmanage -p hello.sh` and all other files fails.